# "You find anything?"

Tags: grammar, tense

I've encountered variations of this phrase ("You find anything?") a few times in different places but mostly in USA series. Could you please tell me why this is grammatically correct?
I thought it should be either:

- Did you find anything?
- [Have] You found anything?

Since I don't remember such weird phrases with other verbs could you please also explain if this verb is special or is it some rule/contraction which is used in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a casual construction.  The words you think should be there, "***did / have***" are in fact there grammatically, but they are omitted when spoken casually because they are the only words that *can* go there, and so they are understood as if they were there.  This construction should not be used in formal situations, or when writing, unless you are writing a quoted conversation.

Comment: And, yes, it can happen with other verbs. "[Do you] Fancy a drink?" "[Are] You coming?"